# How can I get my third floor radiators working?

Tags: heating, radiator

I have two radiators upstairs.  One is slightly warm, and the other is not warm at all, leaving the room very cold.  When I tried to bleed the radiators in the house, all of them released water and are working fine except the upstairs ones.  With the two upstairs radiators only air came out.  At this point, I need the one that isn't releasing heat at all to at least release some. I do not have money to have someone come look at it, and I don't know what to do.  The radiator that isn't working at all is currently turned off, because I read somewhere to do that to allow it to build up water pressure.  Please help! Single house mother needs help.

Comment: Turning off the radiator will not accumulate water pressure, but it will ensure that it doesn't get hot.  Turn it back on.

Answer (score 4):

No need to panic, it's probably pretty simple. It sounds like your system is full of air and just needs to be bled. You've probably bled all the pressure out of the system, so you'll need to re-pressurize it, then bleed the radiators again, then pressurize again, bleed again, until all the air is gone.

Look at your boiler, there should be a pressure gauge on it. It should have a green arc, and maybe a yellow ark before having a red ark. Most likely green will go up to 2 bar(29 psi). Right now the needle is probably on the low end of the scale.

You'll need to find your pressurization valve, and open it until you get some pressure. The pressurization valve is between your home's water supply and the boiler, all you need to do is open it until you get about 1.2 to 1.5 bar and then close it. If you cannot find the valve see if you can find the manual, or just ask a neighbor who seems handy. It's very simple and you shouldn't need to pay anyone to do it.

Be careful not to over-pressurize the system, turn off the pressurization valve before the needle goes into the red.